# NSData object from created from unsigned 64-bit integer is reversed

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

In Xcode 5.0.2 on OS X 10.9.1:

```
uint64_t data = 0x6ffa9e58938d7f5d;
NSData *nsdataObj = [NSData dataWithBytes:&data length:8];
NSLog(@"%@", nsdataObj);
```

Output:

```
<5d7f8d93 589efa6f>
```

How/why is the data getting reversed?

Comment: Google "little endian".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) apparently. (Thanks [@Hot Licks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/581994/hot-licks) and [@Josh Caswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603977/josh-caswell)!) Solved the issue by using the Core Foundation byte order function [CFSwapInt64](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFByteOrderUtils/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001449-CH201-DontLinkElementID_17).

Answer (score 6):

In this brave new world of Intel Macintoshes*, your integers are stored in memory in an absolutely bizzare fashion known as "little-endian byte order". That means that, unlike the more reasonable, human-readable format in which you wrote your number, the Least Significant Bytes, or the bytes of the lowest magnitude, are actually sorted to the beginning of the data. (In the case of your data, the LSB is `0x5d`, followed by `0x7f`, and so on up.)

This doesn't change the value of the integer; if you use the value *as an integer*, the computer knows how to read it back appropriately. On the other hand, `NSData` just scoops the bytes out as they lie in memory, so you see the little-endian order when you print it.

If you need to change the order before creating the `NSData` to the more natural big-endian order -- as Woz intended -- you can use the appropriate [Foundation Byte Ordering function](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIFHJBH).

Check out [this Big Nerd Ranch article](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/835-its-the-endian-of-the-world-as-we-know-it/) for more.

---

*Okay, not really that new anymore.

Comment: I suspect that "little-endian" order goes back to some of the decimal systems of the 50s and early 60s.

Comment: My father likes to grumble that little endian is a choice that hardware engineers make just to ease their own lives, but then he's been writing networking software for thirty-some years. I've just inherited his bias and enjoy a little hyperbole now and then.