# Convert NSData to unsigned int 32 array

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdata

I want to convert the 8 bytes I have in an `NSData` instance to a `uint32_t` array that has 2 items. I did the following, but it's not correct.

```
NSLog(@"Challenge data %@",dataChallenge);
uint32_t *data = (uint32_t *)dataChallenge.bytes;
NSLog(@"data0: %08x, data1: %08x", data[0], data[1]);
```

And this is the result:

```
Challenge data <3ce3e664 dafda14b>
data0: 64e6e33c, data1: 4ba1fdda
```

The order of data is not correct.

The values should be:

```
Challenge data <3ce3e664 dafda14b>
data0: 3ce3e664, data1: dafda14b
```

Comment: What didn't work? Are you sure that there's 8 bytes in `dataChallenge`?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Yes, i'm sure dataChallenge is 8 bytes.

Comment: So _what's going wrong_?

Comment: What didn't work???????

Comment: (Do be aware that "endianness" could be an issue.)

Comment: (Saying that something "is not correct", without any details, is useless.  The first and most important step in solving a problem is accurately characterizing it.)

Comment: Drive somebody crazy...

Comment: And the values should be...???

Comment: You will notice that the values are in opposite order.  Look up "endianness" in Wikipedia.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSData object from created from unsigned 64 bit integer is reversed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21664402)

Comment: @HotLicks: The values should be :Challenge data <3ce3e664 dafda14b>
data0: 64e6e33c, data1: 4ba1fdda

Comment: Isn't that what you got?

Comment: @HotLicks: yes, maybe the problem is little endian.

Comment: To swap byte order there are a set of CF functions, see my added NSLog and Note. Is everybody happy now? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uint32_t *data = (uint32_t *)dataChallenge.bytes;

Example:

```
NSData *dataChallenge = [@"12345678" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"dataChallenge: %@", dataChallenge);
uint32_t *data = (uint32_t *)dataChallenge.bytes;
NSLog(@"data0: %08x, data1: %08x", data[0], data[1]);
```

NSLog output:

> dataChallenge: <31323334 35363738>
>   data0: 34333231, data1: 38373635

Note: The bytes are reversed because this is a lithe-endian machine

With memcpy:

```
NSData *dataChallenge = [@"12345678" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"dataChallenge: %@", dataChallenge);
uint32_t data[2];
memcpy(data, (uint32_t *)dataChallenge.bytes, dataChallenge.length);
NSLog(@"data0: %08x, data1: %08x", data[0], data[1]);
```

NSLog output:

> dataChallenge: <31323334 35363738>
>   data0: 34333231, data1: 38373635

Swapping the byte order:

```
NSLog(@"data0: %08x, data1: %08x", CFSwapInt32BigToHost(data[0]), CFSwapInt32BigToHost(data[1]));
```

NSLog output:

> data0: 31323334, data1: 35363738

Note: See CFByteOrder.h for more combinations of byte swapping.

Comment: This leaves the bytes owned by the `NSData` instance, which may or may not be desirable. `memcpy()`, as the OP is using, means that the data can outlive the `NSData` instance. `-[NSData getBytes:length:]` would also work to accomplish that.

Comment: User's choice. It's about the method.

Comment: @Zaph: I tried your code but the order of data is not correct This is Challlenge data <3ce3e664 dafda14b>
data0: 64e6e33c, data1: 4ba1fdda

Comment: If you're getting the data over the network, @user, it's big-endian now, and you need to swap it to little.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: How can i swap to little endian?

Comment: See the duplicate I proposed.

Answer (score 0):

Below logic converts NSData to integer perfectly. Length of bytes does not matter. It just works.

```
NSData *data;
NSString *stringData = [data description];
stringData = [stringData substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [stringData length]-2)];

unsigned dataAsInt = 0;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: stringData];
[scanner scanHexInt:& dataAsInt];
```